# 502 - web server received an invalid response while acting as a gateway or proxy server. IIS

Tags: iis, reverse-proxy

I have 2 servers (Web & APP Server).

I have hosted my API's on APP Server & APP server is accessed by ARR from Web Server using reverse proxy.

The error is displayed exactly at 2 min after calling the API.

I have increased the time limit in IIS as well.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I updated the timeout in the Application request Routing of Reverse Proxy Server and this resolved my issue.

http://docs.360works.com/index.php/Update_IIS_timeout